# Función Y/N en c++

Tags: c++

¿Cómo hacer que el usuario elija una opción tipo Y/N?

Estoy usando Code Blocks en Ubuntu.

Esto es lo que intenté hasta ahora:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

string Continuar;

int main()
{
    cout << "¿Continuar Y/N?";
    cin>>Continuar;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un if-else luego de tomar el valor de la variable continuar:

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

string Continuar;

int main()
{
  cout << "¿Continuar Y/N?";
  cin>>Continuar;
  if(Continuar=="Y" || Continuar=="y"){
  cout<<"Continuar...";
  }
  else{
    cout << "Salir del programa.";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

O puedes usar un do-while:

```
do
{
cout << "¿Continuar Y/N?";
cin>>Continuar;
} while (Continuar == "Y" || Continuar == "y");
```

Answer (score 1):

En la programación no es una buena práctica el uso de variables globales, además las variables deben empezar con minúsculas y las clases con mayúsculas (es un estándar, no significa que no funcione o que esté mal si no lo hacés así). Para el caso de la elección se puede usar un if/else de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char continuar;
    cout << "¿Continuar Y/N?\n";
    cin >> continuar;

    if(tolower(continuar) == 'y'){
      cout<<"Continuar...\n";
    }else {
        if (tolower(continuar) == 'n')
            cout << "Salir del programa.\n";
        else
            cout << "Opcion invalida...\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```